# InjectionToken produces "Error encountered resolving symbol values statically"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to build a Ionic 3 app with `ionic cordova build ios --prod`

Everything was working fine but suddenly (after a package update I guess) I cannot build anymore.

I think the error is caused by an InjectionToken in app.config.ts that I coded based on [Angular 4 docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectiontoken)

app.config.ts

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export interface OneSignalConfig {
  apiKey: string
};

// PROD Config

export const ONESIGNAL_CONFIG: OneSignalConfig = {
  apiKey: '**apiKey**'
};

export const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

export const mixpanelToken = "**mytoken**";

// COMMON
export let ONESIGNAL_CONFIG_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<OneSignalConfig>('onesignal.config');
```

app.module.ts

```
// Config imports
import { firebaseConfig, ONESIGNAL_CONFIG, ONESIGNAL_CONFIG_TOKEN } from './app-config.ts';
...
// the providers part
providers: [
    ...
    OneSignal,
    { provide: ONESIGNAL_CONFIG_TOKEN, useValue: ONESIGNAL_CONFIG },
...
  ]
```

And this produces the following issue when trying to build :

```
[16:10:19]  ngc started ...
[16:10:27]  typescript error
            Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve ./app-config.ts relative to
            /Users/me/myproj/src/app/app.module.ts., resolving symbol
            AppModule in /Users/me/myproj/src/app/app.module.ts,
            resolving symbol AppModule in
            /Users/me/myproj/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol
            AppModule in /Users/me/myproj/src/app/app.module.ts

Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
    at /Users/me/myproj/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:237:55
    at step (/Users/me/myproj/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/me/myproj/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/me/myproj/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:4:58)
[16:10:27]  copy finished in 7.84 s
```

But it works with `serve`, `run` and `emulate`... it's driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

Try simplify it to something like this:

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";

    export let APP_CONFIG= new InjectionToken<AppConfig >('app.config');

    export interface AppConfig {
      apiKey: string
      // Any other constants you want here.
    }

    export const AppConstants: AppConfig = {
      apiKey: '**apiKey**'
      // Any other values you want here matching above interface.
    }
```

then in your module:

```
// Config imports
import { firebaseConfig, ONESIGNAL_CONFIG, ONESIGNAL_CONFIG_TOKEN } from './app-config.ts';
...
// the providers part
providers: [
    ...
    OneSignal,
    { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: AppConstants },
...
  ]
```

then in your components:

```
...

import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_CONFIG, AppConfig } from '../../app/app.config';

...

constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG)
    private config: AppConfig,
) {
  console.log(this.config.apiKey) // do something with your constants.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have file extension in your import statement. Remove `.ts` from app.module.ts. This should work.

```
import { firebaseConfig, ONESIGNAL_CONFIG, ONESIGNAL_CONFIG_TOKEN } from './app-config';
```

I got a different error message with `ts` so you must be using an older angular version.